# How to convert PCI express to PCI-x

Tags: pci-express, pci

I have a part that outputs PCI-x.  My mother board only takes PCI-express.  I was wondering if there is a way to convert PCI express to PCI-X?

Comment: Questions about PC hardware are off topic here

Comment: could you at least tell us what device you want to use? at this point, I'll bet you *really* don't want to use that device with a bridge, but would be much better off at probably a lower price using a PCIe device instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have a part that outputs PCI-x.

nope. PCI-x is a bidirectional bus; it's not "output" in any direction; the host typically sends an address (and potentially data), and the device reacts to that with data; there's interrupt lines etc.

> My mother board only takes PCI-express. I was wondering if there is a way to convert PCI express to PCI-X?

What you'd need is a "PCI-x bridge"; just like PC hardware often contains (contained) PCI bridges, these should be [commercially available](https://eu.mouser.com/Semiconductors/Interface-ICs/PCI-Interface-IC/_/N-4onfg?P=1ywy2zq). However, these things would, more or less, look like they are most of a motherboard to the PCI-X device. This is not an easy task!

Unless your PCI-X device is really irreplaceable: don't bother. Just get the same darn thing, but with PCIe; PCI-X was a server-targeted bus before the much faster, much more robust, much easier to route (and hence cheaper) PCIe arrived. It's been dead for more than 10 years – so, whatever hardware you have for that bus is probably slow and obsolete by now.

If you really need that PCI-X device, get an old server board and install it in that.

Answer (score -1):

I think those are kind of the same terms and same speed capabilities. I think what you are dealing with is a short pci connector and a longer pci card and or visa versa. If that is correct, then you can get a adapter if the extra height added from the adapter will fit in your computers case.  [pci e 1x to pci e 16](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bhV7Q.png)

[adapter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gqR4U.png)

Comment: PCI-X (PCI Extended) is something entirely different than PCIe (PCI Express).  If the author's hardware only supports PCI-X than their PCIe hardware is not compatible with the system in question.